# Insert bulk records from Db2 to Cassandra using Apache Nifi

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

I am connecting DB2 loading data to Cassandra using Apache Nifi. My Db2 table has over 200+k records and only 400 nos are getting inserted in cassandra target. Getting an error for the remaining like cassandra batch statements cannot insert more than 65535 records. Tried some change in yaml file but did not help, getting the same error. Can i change from Batch to bulk in Nifi? Or if i need to load all the records from Db2 what changes required in Nifi or Cassandra?
[image]
[image]
Log file o/p

```
2019-04-02 13:50:26,786 INFO [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@623cd12e checkpointed with 28 Records and 0 Swap Files in 53 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 18 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 28 millis), max Transaction ID 83
2019-04-02 13:50:30,590 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.p.cassandra.PutCassandraRecord PutCassandraRecord[id=993740ce-0169-1000-7471-e9ff7f0272f6] Unable to write the records into Cassandra table due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement.add(BatchStatement.java:154)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.cassandra.PutCassandraRecord.onTrigger(PutCassandraRecord.java:165)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What processor are you using? And what are the parameters?

Comment: ExecuteSQL at DB2 side and PutCassandraRecord for Cassandra. Using the default LOGGER, BATCH SIze = 100. I made BATCHSIZE to 100000, but did not help.

Comment: You want to say that with batch size 100 you have this error? Could you please edit question and put there parameters and full error from log file.

Comment: @daggett-any suggestions?

Comment: what is the version of nifi ?

Comment: Nifi version - 1.9.1

Comment: according to the [sources](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-cassandra-bundle/nifi-cassandra-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/cassandra/PutCassandraRecord.java#L167) the batch size 100 should work. just interesting if incoming file contains 100 records do you have errors?

Comment: No errors, except the above. It loads upto 400 records and stop with the above error. Is there a setting in Cassandra i have to look into?

Comment: I don't know about Cassandra props. Let's try batch size 2 for example or even 1...

Comment: Ok what i observed is it is loading even with that error. But painfully slow and stopped loading after 1.2 GB or 1000 records. Is there some settings i can tweak in nifi properties to load faster and continue beyond 1000

Comment: it's better to set batch size to 1, otherwise you'll overload Cassandra without necessity... https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html

Comment: @Alex Ott when i set batch size to 1, it is not loading more than a single record

Comment: it was a general comment about Cassandra...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is fixed in 1.10.0. Please consider upgrading apache-nifi

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6016

Comment: Where do you find 1.10.0? I see only 1.9.2 version as the latest.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a batch job? If it is you can use Cassandra ssloader, see https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html

You'll have to create SSTables, then stream them to your Cassandra cluster with ssloader. 200K records should not be a problem.